# Save file with C fopen

Tags: c, file-permissions, fopen

I did a program in C but it does not allow to save on c:\SomeDirectory\afile.txt

I'm using this:

```
FILE* m_hFile = fopen("c:\\SomeDirectory\\afile.txt", "a+t");
fprintf(m_hFile, "testing");
fclose(m_hFile);
```

Why that? Is there a defined folder I can save in?

SomeDirectory is previously created.

I'm using Windows 7 OS.

Comment: `fopen` is from the C standard library, not the C++ standard library.

Comment: @Okami: sufficient access rights problem?

Comment: The `"t"` in your mode string is nonstandard and invalid. And there's certainly no sense in casting an expression of type `FILE *` to `FILE *`.

Answer (score 4):

If `fopen` encounters an error, it sets the `errno` variable indicating what error occurred. You can test this, or even simpler, use `perror` to print out an error message that will tell you what went wrong:

```
FILE* m_hFile = fopen("c:\\SomeDirectory\\afile.txt", "a+t");
if (m_hFile == NULL) {
  perror("fopen");
}
```

Comment: On windows XP it works, on Win 7 the problem appears. I'm executing as administrator...

Comment: Did you try using `perror`? What error message are you getting?

Comment: @Okami: Is that the exact message or is that translated from a different language? In any case, just another note: being logged in as administrator is different from running a program as admin - to do that, you need to start the program as admin, for eg. by right-clicking and using "Run as Administrator".

Comment: @Okami Yes use *"Run as"* on Windows 7 just working on the *Administrator* desktop in not enough.

Comment: @Okami: Yes in Windows Vista and 7 the Administrator user has been nerfed (as they say in MMOs). It no longer has the powers it used to have.

Comment: @Okami: But in any case, I doubt that your program *should* run with admin rights. It is a very rare program that actually needs those rights.

Comment: So where can I save a file if I'm not an administrator? Can't I? Or how to aquire administrator rights?

Comment: @Okami: You should be able to save to the current user's documents directory.

Comment: Which you can find out using the Windows API `SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, lpszPathOut, CSIDL_PERSONAL, FALSE);`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like perhaps "SomeDirectory" doesn't exist.  You can create folders with C++ but you'll want to check if one's already there.  Just calling the open command doesn't automagically create the folder. :)