# Save file in Windows 7

Tags: c, winapi, windows-7, file-permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save file with C fopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048949/save-file-with-c-fopen)

I'm using C language to same a file in c:\SomeDirectory on Windows 7.

Is there any restriction on saving a file under this directory on windows 7?

I'm having trobles with saving this file on this folder, the Windows 7 doesn't allow me (even as administrator) to save the file.

On winXP the program works perfectly.

Comment: Check the permissions on the directory.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the permissions with C language?

Comment: Yes C Drive in which the OS resides will have strong security (this is not much of an issue in Win XP). Why not use other drives?

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048949/save-file-with-c-fopen posted by @Okami a 20min ago.

Comment: -1: exact duplicate.. from the same poster (as Alexandre says)

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that [User Access Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) is enabled on your system?  If you, can you disable for the specified folder and try?